# Microsoft Word: Get User Information from AzureAD / Microsoft 365 Profile

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-addins

Users at our organization need to create word documents from templates. In the document there should be their name, their phone number and email address. Unfortunately in MS Word "user information" only contains the users name, initials and mailing address. So I can't use "normal fields", I think.

Until now, we used a autoexec() word macro / vba script that read the user's information (phone, email, Name) from local AD/LDAP when opening the template and replaced some placeholders in the document template. The user then saved this document as a copy. This solution worked quite well when everyone was working on a domain joined windows computer within the company network. Now people work via word online, iPads, from outside the company network and so on..

Of course one could generate the document via web app or powershell and do a search / replace but that would break the users known workflow. They are already "a bit challenged" by all the changes that came through the switch from good old mapped network drives to sharepoint online etc.

Therefore I'd like to find a solution that looks and works similarly to what they're used to.

Maybe an office add-in that offers templates in a pane with data prefilled from graph api would be an option. Thanks @Tiny-wa for the suggestion.
I really appreciate any hints. Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Have you take [using graph api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#response-1) to get user information into consideration? I mean I'm not familiar with your scenario, and maybe more details?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response! The graph api unfortunately is not accessible from word directly. I've edited the original post.